# Merge Rows in Excel using same columns and 2 different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, row, powerquery

I have data like below.

I need to keep same column on basis of 1,2,3,5,9 and column 6,7,8 need to be combined or merged into one.

For the below example first 8 rows are duplicated but in actual there are 4 rows.
Row 9 and 10 are seperate cases.

what can be the best possible way to do it. I tried to use **vlookup, merge, concat** to make a primary key and merge but somehow all my rows were not found.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 1 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 2 |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 3 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 4 |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| Alpha | DataColumn | massWeight | DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 11 |
| AlphBetaa | DataColumn | massWeight | VERY DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn |  | Type AB | A | state | 12 |

Expected outcome:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz | Type AB |  | state | 1 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz | Type AB |  | state | 2 |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz | Type AB |  | state | 3 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz | Type AB |  | state | 4 |
| Alpha | DataColumn | massWeight | DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 11 |
| AlphBetaa | DataColumn | massWeight | VERY DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn |  | Type AB | A | state | 12 |

Thanks in advance.

When i try the Power Query method, the last column is not coming correct.

[image]

Comment: If you are including `Column9` in the grouping, then you have six (6) different rows, not four (4). Please explain.

Comment: Please provide sample data for the expected output based on your input. Thanks

Comment: expected outcome now attached

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Edited to show updated data sample and result***

Given this data:
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//Group by Cols 1-5 and combine columns 6-9 for each group
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),5), 
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),5), each {_, (t)=>
            List.Distinct(
                List.RemoveNulls(
                    Table.Column(t,_)
                                )
                            ), type list})),

//Expand All Lists
    #"Expanded Lists" = List.Accumulate(
        List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Grouped Rows"),6),
        Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows",Table.ColumnNames(#"Grouped Rows"){5}),
        (state, current)=> Table.ExpandListColumn(state,current)),

//Set data types
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Lists",{{"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", Int64.Type}}),

//sort Column10 as shown in your example output
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"Column10", Order.Ascending}})

in 
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

***Output***
[image]

Comment: Dear Ron Rosenfeld,

Comment: updated output, your code M works but i missed out one column due to which it isn't working , i dont seem to mention list.Transofrm and Table.Group correcrtly, can you help with updated expected output how to change please

Comment: I attached the result from power Query

Comment: @user12063090 Not sure what you are doing incorrectly. All I did was (using the first code contents I provided), was to add `"Column 10"` to the `List.Transform` within the `Table.Group` function and I see `11` and `12` in the last two rows of Column 10. So that part looks like `List.Transform({"Column6","Column7","Column8","Column9","Column10"}, each {_, (t)=>`

Comment: what do you see for the first four rows ? That’s incorrect for me. As you can see in screenshot it’s 1,3 in one row. Not separate rows

Comment: @user12063090 OK, I see now what you want for output. I thought it was the screenshot, but it is not. I have EDITED the answer that shows what you show for output. Note that you have still not clarified your initial statement about including Column9 in determining unique rows, but your examples do not show that, so I have assumed that statement of yours is wrong.